# Generic method to find all TextBox controls in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have several Silverlight controls on a page and want query all the controls that are of type TextBox and have that working.

Now the Silverlight form I'm working on *could* have more TextBox controls added.  So when I test to see if a TextBox control has a value, I could do:

```
if (this.TextBox.Control.value.Text() != String.Empty)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

but I'd rather have if flexible that I can use this on ANY Silverlight form regardless of the number of TextBox controls I have.

Any ideas on how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you need a *recursive* routine like GetTextBoxes below:

```
void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Instantiate a list of TextBoxes
    List<TextBox> textBoxList = new List<TextBox>();

    // Call GetTextBoxes function, passing in the root element,
    // and the empty list of textboxes (LayoutRoot in this example)
    GetTextBoxes(this.LayoutRoot, textBoxList);

    // Now textBoxList contains a list of all the text boxes on your page.
    // Find all the non empty textboxes, and put them into a list.
    var nonEmptyTextBoxList = textBoxList.Where(txt => txt.Text != string.Empty).ToList();

    // Do something with each non empty textbox.
    nonEmptyTextBoxList.ForEach(txt => Debug.WriteLine(txt.Text));
}

private void GetTextBoxes(UIElement uiElement, List<TextBox> textBoxList)
{
    TextBox textBox = uiElement as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        // If the UIElement is a Textbox, add it to the list.
        textBoxList.Add(textBox);
    }
    else
    {
        Panel panel = uiElement as Panel;
        if (panel != null)
        {
            // If the UIElement is a panel, then loop through it's children
            foreach (UIElement child in panel.Children)
            {
                GetTextBoxes(child, textBoxList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instantiate an empty list of TextBoxes. Call GetTextBoxes, passing in the root control on your page (in my case, that's this.LayoutRoot), and GetTextBoxes should recursively loop through every UI element that is a descendant of that control, testing to see if it's either a TextBox (add it to the list), or a panel, that might have descendants of it's own to recurse through.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Many Thanks!

This is definitely what I was looking for.  Now I just need to see if I can the the UIElement class to extract more information.  (i.e. Control x:Name if possible)

Comment: I don't think you can cast a `ScrollViewer` as a `Panel`, so if you might need to get the child of one, you'll need to add another `else`.

Answer (score 14):

I have already faced this issue and notify it here : http://megasnippets.com/en/source-codes/silverlight/Get_all_child_controls_recursively_in_Silverlight

Here you have a generic method to find recursively in the VisualTree all TextBoxes:

```
IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetChildrenRecursively(DependencyObject root)
{
    List<DependencyObject> children = new List<DependencyObject>();
    children.Add(root);
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root); i++)
        children.AddRange(GetChildrenRecursively(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i)));

    return children;
}
```

Use this method like this to find all TextBoxes:

```
var textBoxes = GetChildrenRecursively(LayoutRoot).OfType<TextBox>();
```

Comment: Same Code as VB.Net:Public Shared Function GetChildsRecursive(ByVal Root As DependencyObject) As IEnumerable(Of DependencyObject) Dim Found As New List(Of DependencyObject) Found.Add(Root) For i As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(Root) - 1 Found.AddRange(GetChildsRecursive(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Root, i))) Next Return Found End Function

Answer (score 3):

From your top most panel you can do this (my grid is called ContentGrid)

```
var textBoxes = this.ContentGrid.Children.OfType<TextBox>();
var nonEmptyTextboxes = textBoxes.Where(t => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text));
foreach (var textBox in nonEmptyTextboxes)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

However this will only find the textboxes that are immediate children. Some sort of recursion like below would help, but I'm thinking there must be a better way.

```
private List<TextBox> SearchForTextBoxes(Panel panel)
{
    List<TextBox> list = new List<TextBox>();
    list.AddRange(panel.Children.OfType<TextBox>()
        .Where(t => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text)));

    var panels = panel.Children.OfType<Panel>();
    foreach (var childPanel in panels)
    {
        list.AddRange(SearchForTextBoxes(childPanel));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction.  Is there some sort of way to use Reflection to get information about a control if it's a certain control type?

Comment: What do you mean? The .OfType extension method will only return controls of the type specified. And they'll be typed correctly. What sort of information are you after?

Answer (score 3):

Took [Scott's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5007/scott-ferguson) [initial idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604144/generic-method-to-find-all-textbox-controls-in-silverlight/604485#604485) and expanded it so that it

1. Uses generics, so it easily copes with multiple control types.
2. Supports more container types. In my WP7 I needed to support panaorama's, scroll viewers etc... which aren't Panels. So this allows support for them.
3. Biggest issue is that string comparing, especially on the Panel and derrived items.

Code:

```
private static void GetControls<T>(UIElement uiElement, List<T> controlList) where T : UIElement
{
    var frameworkFullName = uiElement.GetType().FullName;
    if (frameworkFullName == typeof(T).FullName)
    {
        controlList.Add(uiElement as T);
        return;
    }

    if (frameworkFullName == typeof(Panel).FullName ||
        frameworkFullName == typeof(Grid).FullName ||
        frameworkFullName == typeof(StackPanel).FullName)
    {
        foreach (var child in (uiElement as Panel).Children)
        {
            GetControls(child, controlList);
        }
        return;
    }

    if (frameworkFullName == typeof(Panorama).FullName)
    {
        foreach (PanoramaItem child in (uiElement as Panorama).Items)
        {
            var contentElement = child.Content as FrameworkElement;
            if (contentElement != null)
            {
                GetControls(contentElement, controlList);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    if (frameworkFullName == typeof(ScrollViewer).FullName)
    {
        var contentElement = (uiElement as ScrollViewer).Content as FrameworkElement;
        if (contentElement != null)
        {
            GetControls(contentElement, controlList);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar logic to ideas above to also handle controls with a "Content" attribute like TabItems and Scrollviewers where children might be embedded at a lower level.  Finds all children:

```
   IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetControlsRecursive(DependencyObject root)
   {
       List<DependencyObject> elts = new List<DependencyObject>();
       elts.Add(root);
       string type = root.GetType().ToString().Replace("System.Windows.Controls.", "");
       switch (root.GetType().ToString().Replace("System.Windows.Controls.", ""))
       {
           case "TabItem":
               var TabItem = (TabItem)root;
               elts.AddRange(GetControlsRecursive((DependencyObject)TabItem.Content));
               break;
           case "ScrollViewer":
               var Scroll = (ScrollViewer)root;
               elts.AddRange(GetControlsRecursive((DependencyObject) Scroll.Content));
               break;
           default: //controls that have visual children go here
               for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root); i++) elts.AddRange(GetControlsRecursive(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i)));
               break;
       }
       return elts;
   }
```